# Incredibly simple android java question

Tags: java, android

How can I convert the below int to display the result of the sum as text in a textview?

Am getting 'cannot invoke toString() on primitive type int' - thought that was the point of toString!?!

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    txtAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
    editStones = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editStones);

    int result = 10 + 10;
    txtAnswer.setText(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `String.format` to apply formatting to the number is being displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
txtAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

or this works also:

```
txtAnswer.setText("result is : "+result);
```

Comment: Interesting, so if I wanted to extend this to do a simple calc:

Comment: why doesn't this work?
int result = 14 * Integer.valueOf(editStones);

Comment: editStone is an EditText object, you need to do editStone.getText() to get the string content (a String object). So the correct syntax is : int result = 14 * Integer.ValueOf(editStone.getText());

Comment: That makes total sense, except it's highlighting 'valueOf' and telling me: The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)

Comment: sorry then, should have checked it... it's editStone.getText().toString()

Comment: This seems to work: int result = 14 * Integer.valueOf(editStones.getText().toString());  Is this the most efficient way to do things - seems like I'm setting 'getText()' to a string though thought that'd be obvious/set already?!

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.valueOf(result)`

Answer (score 1):

int is a primitive type in Java, meaning it is not a class, and therefore has no toString() method. You can use the Integer class or just use String.valueOf(result).

Answer (score 0):

One of the more annoying things about java is that they still have primitives. So you have to use a Static Method of another class, either String.valueOf() or Integer.toString().

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it using many formats as follows-

1. Convert using Integer.toString(int)

   ```
   int number = -782;
   String numberAsString = Integer.toString(number);
   ```
2. Convert using String.valueof(int)

   ```
   String.valueOf(number);
   ```
3. Convert using Integer(int).toString()

   ```
   String numberAsString = new Integer(number).toString();
   ```
4. Convert using String.format()

   ```
   String numberAsString = String.format ("%d", number);
   ```